# Why are some common-mode chokes rated in ohms instead of henries?

Tags: impedance, inductance, common-mode, ratings, emi-filtering

Some common-mode chokes, including [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CM5441Z161B-10/240-2488-ND/806591), are rated in ohms instead of in henries. Why? Isn't the impedance injected by the common-mode choke entirely frequency dependent? Is there an assumed frequency at which the specified ohm-age is calculated?

Comment: Full data sheet here: http://datasheet.octopart.com/CM5441Z161B-10-Steward-datasheet-14357163.pdf

Comment: Shows the spec is for Z @ 100 MHz.

Comment: Ah, so the answer is that I'm not looking at the freaking data sheet, I'm looking at the part number guide. Bah. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is measured in ohms because it doesn't behave like an inductor. It's inductive at low frequencies, lossy/resistive in between, and capacitive at very high frequencies.

The resistance is usually measured at 100MHz, but check the [datasheet](http://www.lairdtech.com/brandworld/library/CM5441Z161B-10.pdf) to be sure.

[image]

Comment: If you're going to use a ferrite CMC, look where the \$X_L\$ and R plots cross. That is the crossover point, and needs to be lower than the frequencies you're trying to suppress to be of any use.

Comment: @MattYoung Its still useful impedance below the crossover, just mostly inductive (and thus not damping ringing much).

Comment: I think perhaps I could use some clarification. I was looking at this specifically for its property of adding inductance to differential currents in the <5 MHz range. It sounds like it will still do that. It's just not what perhaps most people would use it for. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: You get < 50 ohms at <5MHz if that's okay for you and the rated current is okay, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Useful maybe, but more often than not adding the wrong ferrite will make things worse.

Answer (score 2):

That particular part there is a [ferrite bead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead), not an inductor, so it has no inductance.

Comment: Well to be fair I guess everything has some parasitic inductance but the point being a ferrite is a different animal than an inductor

Comment: I'm not sure if thats entirely corrrect. I think its just a different kind of inductor that has slightly different properties at certain frequencies.

Comment: Even a single, uncoiled wire has inductance. We don't usually use it for such, but it certainly can have an effect on circuits sensitive to inductance.

Comment: You can get into real trouble assuming ferrite beads have no inductance (don't ask how I know). The one he's using has tens of uH inductance at frequencies below the XL-R crossover. That inductance can be quite high Q.